# Wordpress PHP POST/GET method

Tags: php, wordpress, post, get

i have a plugin on my wordpress website which allows custom PHP.
I created a EMail form, but when it comes to sending, its buggy.
When i send the form completely empty, it works, but as soon as i fill in only 1 field, it gives me a 404 error... i tried both POST and GET but both same result.
This is my code: (please don't mind the Dutch text XD)

```
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$age     = $_POST['age'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$issent  = $_POST['issent'];

if(!$name)    {$errorcount++; $error['name']    = "<text style='color:red;'>Voer je naam in A.U.B.</text><br>";}
if(!$email)   {$errorcount++; $error['email']   = "<text style='color:red;'>Voer een E-Mail in A.U.B.</text><br>";}
if(!$age)     {$errorcount++; $error['age']     = "<text style='color:red;'>Voer je leeftijd in A.U.B.</text><br>";}
if(!$subject) {$errorcount++; $error['subject'] = "<text style='color:red;'>Voer een onderwerp in A.U.B.</text><br>";}
if(!$message) {$errorcount++; $error['message'] = "<text style='color:red;'>Voer een bericht in A.U.B.</text><br>";}

if($errorcount > 0 || !isset($issent)){
//Error display
if(isset($issent)){
    echo $error['name'];
    echo $error['email'];
    echo $error['age'];
    echo $error['subject'];
    echo $error['message'];
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
<label>Naam: </label><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo$name; ?>"><br>
<label>E-Mail: </label><input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo$email; ?>"><br>
<label>Leeftijd: </label><input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo$age; ?>"><br>
<label>Onderwerp: </label><input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo$subject; ?>"><br>
<label>Bericht: </label><br>
<textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="message"><?php echo$message; ?></textarea><br>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="issent">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
} else {
$to      = "Myemail";
$headers  = 'From: no-reply@jkctech.nl' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Myemail' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();;

$finalmsg  = "<h1>".$subject."</h1><br><br>";
$finalmsg .= "Naam:      ".$name."<br>";
$finalmsg .= "E-Mail:    ".$email."<br>";
$finalmsg .= "Leeftijd:  ".$age."<br>";
$finalmsg .= "Onderwerp: ".$subject."<br>";
$finalmsg .= "IP: ".$ip."<br>";

$finalmsg .= "Bericht: <br>".$message."<br>";


mail($to,"JKC Mail Form: ".$subject,$finalmsg,$headers);
echo "E-Mail verstuurd! <br>Wij nemen Z.S.M. contact met u op!";
}
```

I dont seem to get it working...
can someone PLEASE help me, ive googled the heck out of it but i wasnt able to fix it.

Comment: Wordpress registers, captures and acts upon some `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables. Your field names are common enough that they might be colliding with one or more of these. I'd prefix all of your variables with some kind of unique namespace, e.g.: `$_POST['so24138113_name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you havent defined and initialized the `$errorcount`.

Just add the following code at starting of your code :

```
$errorcount = 0;
```

Check if that does the job

Actual Issue is with the "name" of the first field of your form i.e "name".

You cannot use "name" as value of "name" key in wordpress. Wordpress uses it internally for different purposes.

change the value for the "name" key to something else and it will work fine.

This issue also arises when u use any of the following values for the "name" key

```
name,date, year, month, day, hour, minute
```

Comment: WOW THANKS MAN! that really helped me!, shame i cant upvote, but i marked it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of plugin for php tags, Can't you use template for this. Add this code to that template and assign that template to this page.

Comment: how do i do that, im quite a wordpress noob, also guys, please dont downvote, this was just the only option i had left